# Android offline speech recognition extra results

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I'm trying to get an array with extra results from the Android Google speech recognition engine using this line:

```
ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

However, this works only when the device is online and connected to the internet.  When it's offline, I get an array containing only one result.

Is there a way to get a multiple results array when I'm offline?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that online, there is a lot of information to be stored if you even try to develop something like that, one approach to your idea could be using the since **JellyBean** available **speechInput**, but as you will see later(if you try to set this mode) you will need to download on your device a language package for it!

if you succeed finding another way, tell me how!